# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined when I add element to array

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a javaScript function that returns the longest string in an array of strings. When I have three elements on the array it works. However if I add another element to the array it breaks and it gives me the error

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

here is my code:

```js
function largest_string(string){
  for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
    if(string[i].length > string[0].length){
      var temp = string[0];
        string[0] = string[i + 1];
        string[i+1] = temp
    }

  }
  return string[0];
}

console.log(largest_string(["one","onetwo","onetwothree","onetwothreefour" ]));
```

Comment: I think you meant `string[i]` not `string[i + 1]` as for the last element `string[i + 1]` will be undefined!

Comment: Yep.  What @ibrahimmahrir said.  Remember that arrays are zero-based.

Comment: @nineBerry I forgot to make changes, at first I wanted to go to the next element.

Comment: Plus you could easely look for the largest string without swaping, just use a variable that store the index of the largest element so far and every time you find a string that is larger than the assumed large one, store the indes in that variable, of course you'll have to assume that the largest is the first at first before entering the loop.

Answer (score 0):

to fix is string[i] not string[i + 1]

Answer (score 0):

```js
function largest_string(string){
  for(var i = 1; i < string.length; i++){
    if(string[i].length > string[0].length){
      var temp = string[0];
        string[0] = string[i];
        string[i] = temp
    }
  }
  return string[0];
}

console.log(largest_string(["one","onetwo","onetwothree","onetwothreefour" ]));
```